# How to decode struct in swift

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have this JsonResponse from the server

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "totalResults": 0,
  "articles": [
    {
      "title": "United places order for 200 Boeing planes, giving two troubled jets a vote of confidence - CNN",
      "author": "Chris Isidore",
      "source": {
        "Id": "cnn",
        "Name": "CNN"
      },
      "publishedAt": "2022-12-13T14:33:00Z",
      "url": "https://www.cnn.com/2022/12/13/business/united-boeing-order/index.html"
    },
    {
      "title": "November CPI: Inflation rose at annual 7.1% over last year - Yahoo Finance",
      "author": "Alexandra Semenova",
      "source": {
        "Id": null,
        "Name": "Yahoo Entertainment"
      },
      "publishedAt": "2022-12-13T14:17:04Z",
      "url": "https://finance.yahoo.com/news/november-cpi-inflation-rises-71-over-last-year-141704528.html"
    },
    {
      "title": "Gold prices jump higher as U.S. CPI rises 7.1% in November - Kitco NEWS",
      "author": "http://www.facebook.com/kitconews",
      "source": {
        "Id": null,
        "Name": "Kitco NEWS"
      },
      "publishedAt": "2022-12-13T13:37:00Z",
      "url": "https://www.kitco.com/news/2022-12-13/prices-jump-higher-as-U-S-CPI-rises-7-1-in-November.html"
    },
]
```

And here is my model struct

```
struct Article: Codable {
    let articles: [ArticleElement]
}

// MARK: - ArticleElement
struct ArticleElement: Codable {
    let title: String
    let author: String?
    let source: Source
    let publishedAt: Date
    let url: String
}

// MARK: - Source
struct Source: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let name: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "Id"
        case name = "Name"
    }
}
```

I get the error that the codingKey ("articles") is not found, here's the full error message:

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "articles", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "articles", intValue: nil) ("articles").", underlyingError: nil))

I have tried to fetch this API and it's returning this error. I have all the required keys and Idk why I am receiving this error.

here is the API I am fetching "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=(apiKey)"
Here's the function that does the API call to the server and decodes the JSON

```
func fetch<T: Decodable>(request: Request, type:T.Type,
                     callback: @escaping (Result<T, Error>)->Void) {
        var urlComponnets = URLComponents(string: request.baseUrl + request.path)
        var queryItems:[URLQueryItem] = []
        for (k, v) in request.params {
            queryItems.append( URLQueryItem(name: k, value: v))
        }
        urlComponnets?.queryItems = queryItems

        let urlsesson = URLSession.shared
        guard let url = urlComponnets?.url else { return }
        let urlReuqest = URLRequest(url: url)

         let dataTask = urlsesson.dataTask(with: urlReuqest) { data, responce, error in
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
             jsonDecoder.dataDecodingStrategy = .deferredToData
             do {
                 let responce = try jsonDecoder.decode(type, from: data!)
                 callback(.success(responce))
             } catch {
                 callback(.failure(error))
             }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

And I am calling the fetch function from the viewModel as such

```
func getArticles(){
        let request = Request(baseUrl:"https://newsapi.org", path:"/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=\(ApiKey)", params: [:], type: "GET", header: [:])
        
    
        networkManager.fetch(request: request, type: Article.self) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let article):
               
                self.articles = article.articles
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                
            }
        }
        
    }
```

where

```
var articles: [ArticleElement] = []
```

Comment: "I have this JsonResponse from the server": Is that the real JSON you are receiving, or the supposed one? There is a high difference between the two. For instance, server could have an issue, or your request is wrongly made, resulting in sending a different JSON. Could you share the request code (hide private parts), and how you decode the response, and the real JSON when it fails?

Comment: Please show the `JSONDecoder` line

Comment: Hi @Larme, thanks for reaching out. Please see the updated version, thanks

Comment: Hi @vadian, thanks for reaching out. Please see the updated version, thanks

Comment: Delete the line `jsonDecoder.dataDecodingStrategy = .deferredToData`. If this doesn't help insert the line `print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!)` right before the JSONDecoder line and see what you get. And – not directly related to the issue – you should  handle the potential error in the data task.

Comment: @vadian, thanks for the suggestion. I was able to debug my fetch() method and was able to run the code. I changed the **request** variable inside my getArticles() to 
`let request = Request(baseUrl:"https://newsapi.org", path:"/v2/top-headlines?", params: ["country":"us", "category":"business", "apiKey":"\(apiKey"], type: "GET", header: [:]) `
It worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by passing all parameters using the `params` argument (instead of hardcoding them in the `path` argument):

> ```
> let request = Request(baseUrl:"https://newsapi.org", path:"/v2/top-headlines?", params: ["country":"us", "category":"business", "apiKey":"ee55178ed2fb43b0a2a721d43d99a5b0"], type: "GET", header: [:])
> ```

Comment: This might fix, but doesn't explain clearly the issue, especially not helping soome one with the issue. The steps are: Check the real response you got, it's not the expected JSON. I guess it was an error one. So then, we focus on the way you construct the URL, and using empty dict in params was wrong, because it was then removing the hard coding ones: `?country=us&category=business&apiKey=\(ApiKey)"`, making just then `.../v2/top-headlines?`, hence wrong URL endpoint.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I was hard coding the params when I was meant to pass it in the **params** dict. So it was sending to the wrong URL.